# Installing QGIS 3.12.x on Ubuntu focal 20.04 architecture mismatch

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, ubuntu

I am trying to install QGIS 3.12 Bucaresti on Ubuntu Focal Fossa following the steps here:

[https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#id20.][1]

First, I have edited the `sources.list` adding the following repository and code name:

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu/  focal main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu/ focal main
```

and the I have updated the packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

However, the update process hits an error

```
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'**
```

The thing is that I don't think I have a i386 architecture, indeed this is the output from

```
uname -a
```

```
5.4.0-21-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 28 13:10:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I check the `InRelease` file from https://qgis.org/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease, the architecture supported is amd64. Which as far as I know from googling is the same as x86_64.

Someone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't advise going to far into the Ubuntu release schedule when working with QGIS. The LTR's of Ubuntu, Mint, etc. work best with the QGIS release schedule...

Comment: Does `deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://qgis.org/ubuntu/  focal main` work? I haven't tried. I would comment your next line about `src` if you don't need it.

Comment: thanks @etrimaille this fixed the issue about architecture mismatch! One little question, why would you comment the line with `src`? now I got another problem when installing. This package `qtbase-abi-5-12-5`, a dependency of `qgis-providers` package, seems not available, even if I have installed correctly `libqt5core5a`. I guess I am going to search about possible fixes now

Comment: I added my comment as answer, if you can vote for it. I'm not sure about your next error.

Comment: as a follow up to the problem about dependencies, today I was able to install qgis without problem. I guess the repository maintainers fixed the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify the platform in your APT line with `[ arch=amd64 ]`:

```
deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://qgis.org/ubuntu/ focal main
```

Source : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272908/apt-looking-for-i386-files-even-though-architecture-is-amd64

You might need to add the key from the qgis.org server:

```
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3
```

Source : https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu

Side note, if you don't need the QGIS source code, you can comment the `deb-src` line.

Source : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20504/the-difference-between-deb-versus-deb-src-in-sources-list

Comment: I followed up your answer but I got the issue that the repository is not signed.
`The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51F523511C7028C3`

Comment: `wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3` Source https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu